Blender Network Proxy settings
Is there a way to configure Blender 4.3 to connect to the network via proxy? My Internet connection is implemented via proxy with authorization (login/password). Without the network, I can't download missing add-ons.


Hello and welcome! I don't think Blender natively has a built-in feature to configure proxy settings directly within its user interface, but you could try setting up your system-level proxy settings through Windows Settings > Network & Internet > Proxy, then Set up your proxy, and provide the necessary server details, including your login and password if required. Can you try this and let me know if this works?

Everything is already set up in the system, but to access the Internet, each program must specify the proxy server address, port, login and password in the settings.

Blender unfortunately does not currently provide a built-in option to input these details directly. It does support environment variables though. Can you try this? You can also pass them from the command line blender --proxy-server=http://username:password@proxy_address:port
